# Get mutliple Cookie in Headers C#

Tags: c#, parsing, cookies

From Fiddler , I can see the Cookie in Request Header
[image]

However, when I tried to parse the Cookie in C# by webresponse HTTP,

```
 var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)WebRequestBuilder
            .GetRequest(new Uri(url))
            .AllowAutoRedirect(false)
            .GetResponse();

        var test = webResponse.Headers;
```

in the test, which is returned the headers containing the Set-Cookie, what I get is just :

> ASP.NET_SessionId=nod1bi3znubfdf55fzre2hye; path=/;
>   HttpOnly,host=SCANDICWEB203; path=/; HttpOnly,ieAlertDisplay=true;
>   path=/,scandic_lb_cookie=1733559050.0.0000; path=/

Not all of the Cookies were returned like evar58,s_sv_sid, scandic_lb_cookie.... I need all of them in order to push those cookies to execute another url.

So what I have to do to get all the cookie from request header like Fiddler in C#?

Comment: Did u tried read cookies like in this example - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bd70eh18(v=vs.100).aspx?

Comment: Or you can check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343789/how-to-get-multiple-set-cookie-from-webresponse :-)